# Delete tags used for transforming via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

**Given the following XML**

```
<osm>
  <node id="1" version="1" timestamp="2016-02-29T01:33:20Z" lat="0.0" lon="0.657002">
    <tag k="Stat_nr" v="40045"/>
    <tag k="Ortsgr_kl" v="0"/>
    <tag k="Town_ID" v="0000"/>
    <tag k="Name2" v="City2"/>
    <tag k="Name1" v="City1"/>
    <tag k="ID" v="8942835"/>
  </node>
  <node id="2" version="1" timestamp="2016-02-29T01:33:20Z" lat="0.93198" lon="0.000">
    <tag k="Land" v="D"/>
    <tag k="ID_Ref" v=""/>
    <tag k="Stat_nr" v="40045"/>
    <tag k="Name1" v="ExampleCity"/>
    <tag k="ID" v="0000"/>
  </node>
</osm>
```

**Using this XSLT transformation to drop specific `tag` elements and one template to append new `tag` elements,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tag[@k!='Stat_nr' and @k!='Name1' and @k!='ID']"/>

  <xsl:template match="tag[@k='ID']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <tag k="test" value="{@v}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces the following XML result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm>
   <node id="1"
         version="1"
         timestamp="2016-02-29T01:33:20Z"
         lat="0.0"
         lon="0.657002">
      <tag k="Stat_nr" v="40045"/>
      <tag k="Name1" v="City1"/>
      <tag k="ID" v="8942835"/>
      <tag k="test" value="8942835"/>
   </node>
   <node id="2"
         version="1"
         timestamp="2016-02-29T01:33:20Z"
         lat="0.93198"
         lon="0.000">
      <tag k="Stat_nr" v="40045"/>
      <tag k="Name1" v="ExampleCity"/>
      <tag k="ID" v="0000"/>
      <tag k="test" value="0000"/>
   </node>
</osm>
```

But how can I additionally remove the Tags where i took the variables from: The `@k!='ID']tags`

```
<tag k="ID" v="8942835"/>
<tag k="ID" v="0000"/>
```

I tried several variations of the

```
<xsl:template match="tag[@k!='Stat_nr' and @k!='Name1' and @k!='ID']"/>
```

part.
But it either then did not produce the desired result anymore (add the the nods) or just did not delete any tag at all or to many tags (some i wanted to keep). I also placed it at different positions in the code but all that did not work.

Is it possible to do that without a second XSLT file?

p.s. Its a follow up question to this post:
[How to remove and add select elements via XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691270/how-to-remove-and-add-select-elements-via-xslt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a somewhat different approach:

**XSLT  1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tag[@k='Stat_nr' or @k='Name1']"/>
        <tag k="test" value="{tag[@k='ID']/@v}"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Going with your original stylesheet, you would have to change:

```
  <xsl:template match="tag[@k='ID']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <tag k="test" value="{@v}"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

to:

```
  <xsl:template match="tag[@k='ID']">
    <tag k="test" value="{@v}"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

But really, it can be done with less.